# Get Maximum Value from multiple rows of multiple columns using LINQ?

Tags: linq, linqpad

I'm using `LINQPad` to evaluate my linq query. My query goes like this:

```
from o in MyTableFirst
join p in MyTableSecond on o.TheName equals p.TheName
where p.TheName == "CBA-123" && !p.Removed && 
   (o.ReturnPeriod ==100 || o.ReturnPeriod ==10)
select new {
   HMax1 = o.MaxValue1,
   HMax2 = o.MaxValue2,
   HMax3 = o.MaxValue3
}
```

This query can return 0 or some number of rows.

In LINQPad, it return me something like this:

**HMax1**   **HMax2**   **HMax3**
21.1        *null*         22.5
*null*         24.6        11.5

Now, how am I going to get the Maximum value out for these return rows & columns?
I'm expecting return of **24.6**.
Thank You

Comment: what does `MyTableFirst` look like? and what is the type of `o.MaxValue1`?

Comment: 'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTableFirst](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [TheName] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
 [ReturnPeriod] [smallint] NULL,
 [MaxValue1] [float] NULL,
 [MaxValue2] [float] NULL,
 [MaxValue3] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]`

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTableSecond](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [TheName] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
 [Removed] [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: INSERT INTO MyTableSecond VALUES (
 'CBA-123',
 0);

Comment: INSERT INTO MyTableFirst VALUES (
 'CBA-123',
 10,
 21.1,
 NULL,
 22.5);
INSERT INTO MyTableFirst VALUES (
 'CBA-123',
 100,
 NULL,
 24.6,
 11.5);

Comment: thanks. I'll look at it as soon as I can

Comment: Mine works fine. Are you using Entity Framework or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
(from o in db.MyTableFirsts
 join p in db.MyTableSeconds on o.TheName equals p.TheName
 where p.TheName == "CBA-123" && !p.Removed &&
 (o.ReturnPeriod == 100 || o.ReturnPeriod == 10)
  select new
  {
    Maximum = Math.Max(
       Math.Max((float)(o.MaxValue1 ?? 0), (float)(o.MaxValue2 ?? 0)),
       (float)(o.MaxValue3 ?? 0)
    )
  }).OrderByDescending(o => o.Maximum).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or instead of .OrderByDescending(o => o.Maximum).FirstOrDefault(), you can use .Max(o => o)

Comment: Is it because of some fields having *null* values??

Comment: We change every null value to 0 (o.HMax3 ?? 0), so that shouldn't be the problem. As far as I can see, the only reason why there is no result should be because the query doesn't generate any records. You should try changing the select part with something like this:
select new { Val = o.HMax1 }).ToList(), just to see whether your query returns anything. Also, just note that I didn't test this in linqpad. I just wrote a console app to test the query.

Comment: I just ran the query against the tables you provided in your post (ran the scripts to create the tables and insert the records), and I got a result, but commented out the o.Level expression from the where part. This was again a console app.

Comment: My original query (look at Question posted), return result (2 rows of record). Your query make a lot of sense. But why when running on my machine, it doesn't return anything???? Not sure how LINQPad works.Does it compiled based on Visual Studio installed in my machine? I'm using VS 2010, I believed C#4 compiler.....

Comment: OK, I see that I mixed the query a little bit. Sorry about that. Try again with the query above.

Comment: Thanks. Your query is fine. Tested correct when I create a console program. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(
 from o in MyTableFirst
 join p in MyTableSecond on o.TheName equals p.TheName
 where p.TheName == "CBA-123" && !p.Removed && 
 (o.Level ==100 || o.Level ==10)

 //combine all of the numbers into one list
 let listOfNumbers = new List<double?>{o.MaxValue1,o.MaxValue2,o.MaxValue3}

 //select the list
 select listOfNumbers
)
.SelectMany(c => c) //combine all the lists into one big list
.Max(c => c) //take the highst number
```

Comment: Try run this query on LINQPad, it gave me this message:
*NotSupportedException: Parameterless aggregate operator 'Max' is not supported over projections.*

Comment: @mADy1270 Mine works just fine (also in LinqPad) - make sure you have all the brackets set correctly. Edited my answer to make it more clear

Comment: I copied and pasted everything on my LINQPad. Still giving me the same message. I'm using LINQPad 4.43.06.

Comment: @mADy1270 me to. Make sure it is set to "Expression" if you cpoy/pasted directly from my code :)

Comment: Yup. It set to "Expression". Strange...Did I miss some other configuration?

Comment: @mADy1270 I really dont understand. but try replacing `.Max()` with `.Max(c => c)`

Comment: *ArgumentException: The argument 'value' was the wrong type. Expected 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double]'. Actual 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Double]]'.*

Comment: Replace the list with `new List<double?>{...}` I have updated answer

Comment: @mADy1270 Could you E-mail me the exact code? including the type `MyTableFirst`?

Comment: Thanks. Your query is fine. Tested correct when I create a console program. Thanks a lot :D